# Podem me indicar algum package para Sublime Text que melhore o auto completar?

Tags: php, sublime-text-3

Boa noite pessoal. Estava querendo saber se existe algum package para Sublime Text que melhore o auto-complete do mesmo. Gostaria que o Sublime pudesse acessar as classes PHP que incluí no meu código e sugerisse no auto-complete os métodos contidos nelas, mas não conheço nenhum package que faça isso. Conhecem algum que podem me indicar? Agradeço.

Comment: Queria muito saber também. Acho que só usando IDEs que é possível. Mas aguardo respostas.

Comment: O VS Code faz isso, depois de uma pesquisada sobre VS Code, tem muita gente migrando do Sublime para ele por causa disso. Inclusive o VSCode tem um plugin que importa todos os atalhos do Sublime etc... https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.sublime-keybindings

Comment: Gostei bastante do VS Code também, acho que vou migrar pra lá, obrigado pelo comentário!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o PHP Completions Kit.
Segue o link com as instruções,espero ter ajudado.

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PHP%20Completions%20Kit